# echo $PATH returns crazy result, is this going to cause issues?

Tags: path, terminal

When I type in echo $PATH I get

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

That looks crazy redundant. Is this okay/is it going to cause any problems? If not how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any redundancy, the `:` delimits different paths and folders in the PATH are not recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't unusual, and it isn't redundant. Unix-like systems split the path on `:`, so your path contains the following directories:

- `/usr/bin`
- `/bin`
- `/usr/sbin`
- `/sbin`
- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/local/sbin`

Different kinds of binaries live in each of these locations. You don't specify your operating system, but this [FreeBSD manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier) gives an overview of how it treats these directories.

Various Linux distributions treat these directories a little differently, but the principle still holds.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally normal.

If you try to run a application it will search the left most path first for the executable.

Comment: This *does* provide an answer.